# How do I adapt a specific web page to iPad users

Tags: html, css, ipad, web

I have created a special folder within my website directory for iPhone (NOT iPad) users. On my index's heading I have the following code: `<script type="text/javascript"> if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) { document.location = "mobile/";}</script>`

I want the website to be regular for iPad users, **except** for a specific page. I want this particular page within the website to be different for iPad (NOT iPhone) users. How do I do that?...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to include a specific JavaScript file, check the `window.location.pathname` inside an IIFE.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        if(window.location.pathname === 'specific-page') {
           // insert CSS or change stuff
           return false;
        }
    })();
</script>
```

But seriously, just add a custom JS file inside the HTML for this page.

Comment: Do I include this within the heading? within script tags?

Comment: Thanks. But this is not specific to iPad users, right?

Comment: I haven't included your iPad snippet no, this is merely a way to invoke functions on a custom page.